# Raycasting doesn't work as I expected in Unity, it is not infinite, but why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So I made a little program to test ray casting in Unity.
Here is my code: (this is attached to the box)

```
public class BoxScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up);
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Ground") {
                Debug.Log ("Érzékeltem a földet");
            }
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.up, Color.green);

    }
}
```

I thought that I will see an infinite green line what points downwards. It looks down but it is not infinite. If I turn of the boxCollider2D it is the same.
And I can't see the debug message. If it would be infinite than I should see it because it hits the ground object. Am I right?

You can see here the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXiAi.jpg

Why is it not infinite? And how to fix this?

Comment: How would you draw an infinite ray on an finite plane (your screen)?

Comment: print hit.collider.tag and see what it is hitting . i think it is hitting box thats why your log is not comming . try this if(hit != null){ debug.log("tag  " + hit.collider.tag.tostring() )}

Comment: @Nain I tried it and it shows: **tag Box**. This is the code: `void Update () {

  RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector3.up, 2);
  Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.up*2);
  if (hit != null) {
   Debug.Log ("tag " + hit.collider.tag.ToString ());
  }

 }`

Comment: @Nain But it does not detect Ground. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The Debug.DrawRay() method does not draw an infinite ray. It draws a line with a length equal to the magnitude given. In this case, -Vector2.up which is equal to -(1, 0). Your actual raycast should really be infinite in length though.

You may be able to get it to draw "infinitely" by modifying it like

```
Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.up * Mathf.Infinity, Color.green);
```

Alternatively, replace Mathf.Infinity with a very large number.

Comment: Thanks, but why I can't see the debug message? If it's infinite, than it must hit the ground object.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
detectGround = Physics2D.Linecast (sightStart.position, sightEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Grounds"));
    Debug.DrawLine (sightStart.position, sightEnd.position, Color.green);
```

Debug.Drawline only shows in Scene mode not in game mode if you on gizmo it will show in game mode also
Note: You have to set ray position correctly

Comment: Linecast returns with a `bool` but that's not good for me because I want to know what it hits

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add a BoxCollider2D component to your ground object and remove collider from your box object and try following code.

```
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector2.up * 1000.0f);
    if(hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log ("tag" + hit.collider.tag.ToString());
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Ground") {
            Debug.Log ("Érzékeltem a földet");
        }
    }
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.up * 1000.0f , Color.green);
```

also see if there is a warning when you add BoxcCllider2D to  your ground in this case adjust size of collider so that it is not very small.

Comment: But if there is no Collider on the Box than it won't stay on the ground

Comment: Ok then simply add a BoxCollider instead of a BoxCollider2D to your box but your ground will have a BoxCollider2D attached to it.

Comment: you are casting a 2DRayCast it will count a hit only when it hits 2D collider. so adding a 3d collider will prevent falling your box but ray cast will ignore your box and will hit ground or any other box having 2d collider.

Comment: Thank you,now I understand it.

Comment: If this solves your problem kindly mark this as an answer.